# Publish custom web-service on JBoss SOA

Tags: java, jboss, wsdl

I'm hitting a wall with this, currently I have two web-service endpoints configured and running in JBoss Soa 5 and as in ESB standard every endpoint is published as an individual operation.

One end-point for transaction submission:

```
<service description="writes Transactions to DB." name="TransactionsSubmit">
      <listeners>
        <jms-listener busidref="transactionSubmitChannel" name="transactionSubmit" />
            </listeners>
    <actions faultXsd="/resources/xsd/transactions-fault.xsd"
        inXsd="/resources/xsd/ws-submit-trx.xsd"
        mep="RequestResponse"
        outXsd="/resources/xsd/ws-trx-response.xsd">                
        <action     class="org.timo.service.SubmitTransaction">
        </action>
    </actions>
</service>
```

and other for error submission:

```
<service description="writes errors to DB." name="ErrorsSubmit">
      <listeners>
        <jms-listener busidref="errorSubmitChannel" name="errorSubmit" />
            </listeners>
    <actions faultXsd="/resources/xsd/transactions-fault.xsd"
        inXsd="/resources/xsd/ws-errorsubmit-trx.xsd"
        mep="RequestResponse"
        outXsd="/resources/xsd/ws-errorsubmit-response.xsd">                
        <action     class="org.timo.service.SubmitError">
        </action>
    </actions>
</service>
```

What I want to do is to create a custom web-service using my own WSDL file to publish these two operations in a single `proxy` service redirecting the flows to the already defined services `ErrorsSubmit` and `TransactionsSubmit`.

It's possible to do this?

Note: I could deploy my own WSDL service by adding a WAR application to the ESB package, but I can't redirect the flow to the internal services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several weeks I could find the way to do it. By default there is not a configurable way to redirect from a WS-operation to an ESB-service, but you can do it programmatically.

This is the WS-operation:

```
public Response submitTransaction(final TransactionRequest request) throws CommonFault {
        log.info("submitTransaction : "+ request.getId());
        JAXBElement<TransactionResponse> response = invokeService("TransactionsSubmit", objectFactory.createSubmitTransactionRequest(request));
        return response.getValue();
    }


private <T> JAXBElement<T> invokeService(final String serviceName, final JAXBElement<?> request) {
        log.info("Invoking service : " + serviceName + "()");
        JAXBElement<T> response = null;
        try {
            ServiceInvoker serviceInvoker = new ServiceInvoker("myservice", serviceName);
            Message message = org.jboss.soa.esb.message.format.MessageFactory.getInstance().getMessage();

            message.getBody().add(jaxbHandler.serialize(request));
            Message esbResponse = serviceInvoker.deliverSync(message, 5000);
            log.info("Response : " + esbResponse.getBody().get().toString());

            response = deserialize(esbResponse.getBody().get().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e, e);
        }
        return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is a content based router with soap clients.

Comment: Could you please explain it better (I'm quite slow with short answers). What I did (and it works) was to create a proxy web-service that calls the ESB-services by creating SOAP requests in runtime (using the java SOAPMessage native components). Am I close to your approach?